Users requesting editor access to GAS project
In a GAS project used in a Google Chat app, when some users try to install the app it says they need editor access to the GAS project, so a mail comes to me with this request.

The app is published on the company's Workplace Marketplace, the GAS project is shared (read only) to everyone in the domain and the users that asks permisson are in the same domain.

Can anyone help me find a solution without sharing the GAS app as editor to the users?

If you have deployed the app appropriately, you won't have to share the project with anyone other than the people developing it. Please review thoroughly the guide for this task https://developers.google.com/workspace/chat/quickstart/apps-script-app. If you still need help, please edit the question to make it more focused.

Thanks! That's exactly the guide I followed from the begining, and also this one to publish the app on marketplace.
I did every step on both and only shared the GAS project with the domain when the requests to access it started coming.
I don't know what I could say to make the question more focused, tbh. I just want to make sure the users can use the app without sharing the GAS project as editor to them.

@Paulo Why were they asking for edit access? Could show what they saw on their screen that made them ask for edit access?  What's the flow here?

As what @TheMaster have said, kindly edit the question above and add images of what your users saw that prompted them to request edit access. By doing so, it will help other community members better understand your issue.

Thanks and sorry TheMaster and Gyul, I didn't have the time to check this today, I'll get a user on a meet tomorrow and take the screenshots needed.
